# plotly doesn't show anything

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, plotly

Just copied paste [this](https://plot.ly/~jackp/17421/plotly-candlestick-chart-in-python/) example from plotly. Changed in the end to `py.plot` and ran with my dataframe data of course. However python ends normally without any errors and with nothing on the screen to show.

I do get due:

```
Aw, snap! We don't have an account for ''. Want to try again? You can authenticate with your email address or username. Sign in is not case sensitive.

Don't have an account? plot.ly
Questions? support@plot.ly
```

So I tried (with no luck) adding this at the top:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
```

Comment: You either need to register or plot it offline by using `import plotly ploly.offline.init_notebook_mode()` and then use `plotly.offline.iplot(...)`

Comment: this return me unresolved error. tried few combinations....

Answer (score 0):

Using @Maximilian's answer above:

```
import plotly
ploly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
plotly.offline.iplot(...)
```